# Javascript hides navigation when class not found

Tags: javascript, css, class

I have a piece of javascript code for a sub-menu to stay in the viewport when it touches the top, and stops scrolling when it hits the footer.

The script works fine, but on pages where the sub-menu doesn't exists, the main navigation is hiding... Does any one has an idea why this conflict shows up when the class is not found on the page, that the navigation will not be visible...

The code:

```js
$stick = $('.pm-sidebar-menu-container');
$foot = $('footer');
margin = 200;
offtop = $stick.offset().top - margin;
offbtm = $foot.offset().top - (margin * 2 + $stick.height());

$(window).scroll(function() {
  scrtop = $(window).scrollTop();
  if (scrtop > offtop && $stick.hasClass('natural')) {
    $stick.removeClass('natural').addClass('fixed').css('top', margin);
  }
  if (offtop > scrtop && $stick.hasClass('fixed')) {
    $stick.removeClass('fixed').addClass('natural').css('top', 'auto');
  }
  if (scrtop > offbtm && $stick.hasClass('fixed')) {
    $stick.removeClass('fixed').addClass('bottom').css('top', offbtm + margin);
  }
  if (offbtm > scrtop && $stick.hasClass('bottom')) {
    $stick.removeClass('bottom').addClass('fixed').css('top', margin);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *but on pages where the sub-menu doesn't exists*

What you can do is, execute the following function only when that is existing. Let's say the submenu class is `.sub-menu`. Change your code this way:

```js
if ($(".sub-menu").length > 0) {
  $stick = $('.pm-sidebar-menu-container');
  $foot = $('footer');
  margin = 200;
  offtop = $stick.offset().top - margin;
  offbtm = $foot.offset().top - (margin * 2 + $stick.height());

  $(window).scroll(function() {
    scrtop = $(window).scrollTop();
    if (scrtop > offtop && $stick.hasClass('natural')) {
      $stick.removeClass('natural').addClass('fixed').css('top', margin);
    }
    if (offtop > scrtop && $stick.hasClass('fixed')) {
      $stick.removeClass('fixed').addClass('natural').css('top', 'auto');
    }
    if (scrtop > offbtm && $stick.hasClass('fixed')) {
      $stick.removeClass('fixed').addClass('bottom').css('top', offbtm + margin);
    }
    if (offbtm > scrtop && $stick.hasClass('bottom')) {
      $stick.removeClass('bottom').addClass('fixed').css('top', margin);
    }
  });
}
```